# TypeError: unbound method strftime() must be called with datetime instance as first argument (got str instance instead) at Form1, line 38

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I am trying to have my code display my "def timer_progress_tick(self, **event_args):" in HH:MM:SS instead of just seconds.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html - looking at pythons datetime library.

```
 from datetime import datetime

 def timer_progress_tick(self, **event_args):
   """This method is called Every [interval] seconds. Does not trigger if 
   [interval] is 0."""
     if self.start_time is not None:
       self.label_time_elapsed.text = "{}".format(
         datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S', (datetime.now() - self.start_time))
       )
```

i get this;

TypeError: unbound method strftime() must be called with datetime instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
at Form1, line 38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong using `strftime`. It is method of object not a callable from module.

```
self.label_time_elapsed.text = "{}".format(
         (datetime.now() - self.start_time).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
       )
```

Comment: so what should i use? strptime?

Comment: you can use it like this : `(datetime.now() - self.start_time).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: i also added it to answer.

Comment: my "self.start_time = timedelta.now()" in "def button_start_click(self,**event_args):" now gets me "AttributError: 'timedelta' object has no attribute 'now'. What attribute should 'timedelta' object have to replace 'now'